# Return value from cypress custom command and reuse in another function in test.cy.js file

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation, cypress-custom-commands

I have created a custom command `cy.createUser("userCreate")` in `commands.js` that creates a `userID` variable.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("createUser", (payload) => {
    cy.makeUserviaAPI(payload).then((userID) => {
    cy.openUserProfile(userID);
    })
});
```

I want to use this `usedID` in other methods also in my test.cy.js file. i.e. I want to pass `userID` as a variable in new method `cy.updpateUser(userID)`

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.createUser("userCreate")
    cy.updpateUser(userID)
});
```

I have tried  following modifications:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("createUser", (payload) => {
    cy.makeUserviaAPI(payload)
    .then((userID) => {
    cy.openUserProfile(userID);
    })
    .then((userID) => {
            return userID;
    })
});
```

```
beforeEach(() => {

let uid = cy.createUser("userCreate")
    cy.updpateUser(uid)
});
```

But I am getting `userID` as null or with some windows object. Can someone please please guide me on how to pass return variable `userID` and use it in new function as `updateUser(userID)` in `test.cy.js`.

NOTE: I can't move `updateUser()` inside `createUser()` as they needs to be independent of each other.
Also there will be multiple functions in future that will be needing `userID` as primary parameter to operate.

Answer (score 3):

Since you specify one spec file `test.cy.js`, it is possible to use an [alias](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases) to wrap the value of `userID`.

Here I have simple versions of your commands to show the value `abc` is persisted in the right places:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('makeUserviaAPI', () => {
  const userID = 'abc'                           // simple assign and return result
  return userID
})

Cypress.Commands.add('openUserProfile', () => { 
})

Cypress.Commands.add("createUser", (payload) => {
  cy.makeUserviaAPI(payload).then((userID) => {
    cy.openUserProfile(userID)
    cy.wrap(userID).as('userID')                 // publish the userID 
  })
})

Cypress.Commands.add('updateUser', (userID) => {
  expect(userID).to.eq('abc')                     // checking - it passes
})

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.createUser("userCreate").then(userID => {
    cy.updateUser(userID)
  })
})

it('test1', () => {
  cy.get('@userID').should('eq', 'abc')                   // checking - it passes
  cy.get('@userID').then(userID => cy.updateUser(userID)) // passes call to update                  
})

it('test2', () => {
  cy.get('@userID').should('eq', 'abc')                   // checking - it passes
  cy.get('@userID').then(userID => cy.updateUser(userID)) // passes call to update    
})
```

Comment: userID is getting dynamically generated by cy.makeUserviaAPI(). I can't assign hardcode value in beginning. thx though

Comment: It does not matter how you assign `userId` (hardcoded or generated), your question was about persisting it. This works either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same by adding a .then block at end and wrapping the variable that you need as a parameter in test.cy.js function.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("createUser", (payload) => {
cy.makeUserviaAPI(payload)
.then((userID) => {
cy.openUserProfile(userID);
})
.then(() => {
    cy.log('userID=========>', userID) //Added log for verification
    cy.wrap(userID);
    return cy.wrap(userID);
});
})
```

});

test.cy.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add("createUser", (payload) => {
cy.makeUserviaAPI(payload).then((userID) => {
.then(userID=>{
        cy.log('userID=========>', userID) //Added log for verification
cy.openUserProfile(userID);
 })
})
```

});